# What is "remote debugging" on tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat, remote-debugging

I'm not asking *how to do it*. I'm asking **what it is**. I asked my coworkers if we could setup remote debugging on our smoke-testing server and step through the code in eclipse from our developer PCs, and they looked at me funny.

Does remote debugging mean something other than "debug just like always, but remotely, with an IDE on your computer and the application running on a different machine"?

I've never done it and it looks like something that will take me hours to setup, and I doubt I could get permission to research it just to find out if it is what I hoped it was, so I'm asking you all if it is what I hope it is.

Comment: I mean, when I asked, they were like "well, you can connect to the database and look at the content of the tables, but that's all." I asked if it was possible to step through code remotely and got negative head shakes back.

Comment: This is with Tomcat 7, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can start the server in debug mode and connect to it from another machine using Eclipse.  It is not hard to setup, read here: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing

It works exactly as you describe, using JPDA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Debugger_Architecture

Comment: Thank you! I'll bring it up again with confidence. >:)